# Want to click on a input element after searching for text from another div element

Tags: webdriver

I need to search for a keyword in the `span` element (class "D") and then based on the matching criteria, I want to click on the *Choose* `input` element button.

Assuming I am searching for "Test", I would like to see working code on how to achieve this.

Example markup:

```html
<div class="A">
    <div class="B">
        <input class="C" type="submit" onclick="AddFacility(this)" data-facilityid="300075" value="Choose">
    </div>
    <div class="D">
        <span class="js-open-more-info">Test</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to search for a keyword in <span class="js-open-more-info">Test</span> element and then based on the matching criteria (suppose if I am searching for Test) I want to click on the 'Choose' button of span in <input class="C" type="submit" onclick="AddFacility(this)" data-facilityid="300075" value="Choose">
</div>

Please help.

Comment: Please stop asking for help. It is really annoying and makes everyone not want to help you.

Comment: If you dont wanna suggest or HELP anything dont comment on this.

Comment: What I mean is that you do not understand the culture of the site. This is a help site, so of course people are here to help. The way to actually GET help is by rephrasing your question, cleaning it up, making it easy for people to actually help you. If you post something on SO, we KNOW you are probably desperate for help, so there is no point in underlining your need, as it will not make anyone more inclined to alleviate it ...

Comment: And you need to interact with the people answering you. @Vicky posted an answer. Be grateful and award her the answer if it helps you, and comment on it if it fails to do so.

Comment: You should also add some tags that will help people in knowing what programming language you work with. WebDriver has APIs for most programming languages. Is Vicky correct with her Java attempt?

Comment: Heh, Vicky is a guy.  :p Globalization FTW.

Answer (score 2):

Below is an code sample in java

```java
//Get the text from span
String text = driver
        .findElement( By.xpath("//span[@class='js-open-more-info']") )
        .getText();

//if the text is equal to Test then click on the button
if( text.equals("Test") ){
    driver.findElement( By.xpath("//input[@class='C']") ).click();
}
```

**EDIT**

For dealing with multiple divs of same structure sample html(just tweaked ur html and added multiple divs)

**HTML**

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="A">
    <div class="B">
        <input class="C" type="submit" onclick="AddFacility(this)" data-facilityid="300075" value="Choose">
    </div>
    <div class="D">
        <span class="js-open-more-info">Test1</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="A">
    <div class="B">
        <input class="C" type="submit" onclick="AddFacility(this)" data-facilityid="300075" value="Choose">
    </div>
    <div class="D">
        <span class="js-open-more-info">Test2</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="A">
    <div class="B">
        <input class="C" type="submit" onclick="AddFacility(this)" data-facilityid="300075" value="Choose">
    </div>
    <div class="D">
        <span class="js-open-more-info">Test3</span>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
<script>
document.getElementsByClassName('C')[2].addEventListener("click", myFunction);
function myFunction() {
    alert('deleted');
}
</script>
</html>
```

**Code in Java**

```
 //get all the divs into a list
    List<WebElement> divs = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='A']"));
            //loop through the list
            for(int i=0;i<divs.size();i++)
            {
                //get text of all the span elements inside multiple divs
              String text=divs.get(i).findElement(By.xpath(".//span[@class='js-open-more-info']")).getText();

                System.out.println(text);

                //if text of span element is equal to Test3 click on the respective delete button
                if(text.contentEquals("Test3")){

                    divs.get(i).findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@class='C']")).click();

                }
            }
```

Hope this helps you....Kindly get back if you need any further help

Comment: Hi @swapnil377 did the above solution help you...or did i misunderstood your question

Comment: Hi Vicky, Thanks for your suggestion but this approach wont help if there are multiple divs of the same structure. In which suppose I have multiple divs and want to find a specific text and then click on the delete link for that specific element. Please let me know if you have any approach for the same.

Comment: @Swapnil377 I have added a solution for multiple divs added a sample html to try out the script as well.Kindly chk and get back

Comment: Thanks a lot vicky. I tried the solution and works fine.

Comment: @Swapnil377  Happy to be of help...If the above post answers your question..then pls do accept the answer.You can accept the answer by clicking the tick mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green.

Comment: Hi Vicky, There is a slight change in the structure where span has id instead of class. So my structure would be :                                          <div class="A">
    <div class="B">
        <input class="C" type="submit" onclick="AddFacility(this)" data-facilityid="300075" value="Choose">
    </div>
    <div class="D">
        <span class="some unique id">Test</span>
    </div>
</div>                                                                                                       Can u help me for same scenario and for multiple divs ????

Comment: Some changes in the above solution helped :)